# find list of files, make a directory and copy those files in linux

Tags: linux, cp

For example, I want to copy the "file-to-be-copied.txt" from different directories

```
/home/user1/file-to-be-copied.txt
/home/user2/file-to-be-copied.txt
/home/user3/file-to-be-copied.txt
```

Then create a new directory based on the user account

```
/home/user4/user1/
/home/user4/user2/
/home/user4/user3/
```

Then copy the "file-to-be-copied.txt" to the new created directories

```
/home/user4/user1/file-to-be-copied.txt
/home/user4/user2/file-to-be-copied.txt
/home/user4/user3/file-to-be-copied.txt
```

All I know is that it should be done using bash scripting but I don't know how. This is as far as I go

```
find /home . "file-to-be-copied.txt" | xargs -i mkdir ... cp {} ...
```

Answer (score 2):

No find necessary, and more so: no xargs (which is almost always superfluous with find, since find has -exec).

```
cd /home
cp --parents user?/file-to-be-copied.txt user4
```

Comment: Elegant, but definitely Linux-only. `cp` from GNU coreutils 8.5 supports `--parent` while `cp` on Mac OS X (probably from FreeBSD userland?) does not.

Comment: Shouldn't the cp option be _--parents_ ([Gnu cp manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cp-invocation.html) )?  I assumed it was a typo but my suggested edit to fix the answer was rejected twice.

Comment: @SteveMadsen: Since the question is tagged "Linux", I guess you excuse it. And AFAIK GNU-cp is Free and Open Source, so it can be used on more platforms than just Linux.

Comment: Cool, I thought I was going mad :)

Comment: The man page documents it as `--parents`, but it also works without the "s".

Comment: @SteveMadsen: Yes, maybe I tested it from memory and it worked without 's'.

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in $(/usr/bin/find '/home' -name 'file-to-be-copied.txt'); do
  tmpname=${f%/*}
  dirname=${tmpname##*/}
  /bin/mkdir -p $dirname && /bin/cp -p $f $dirname
done
```

Comment: I think the `mkdir&&cp` part is a little wrong: it should copy to `/home/user4`.

Comment: home and file-to-be-copied.txt don't need masking.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used.

```
    for f in $(find '/home' -name 'file-to-be-copied.txt')
      do
        tmpname=${f%/*}
        dirname=${tmpname##*/}
        mkdir -p /home/user4/$dirname && /bin/cp -p $f /home/user4/$dirname

        echo $f copied to /home/user4/$dirname
      done
```